# Best database to package with client application

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing a new application for a customer.  I will be writing it using C#.  My question is this, what database should I use?  I don't want the client to have to install a database.  I just want the database files (hopefully renamed to something the customer won't recognize) to be installed in the folder with the application.  Like putting MDF files in the folder.  So what should I use?  SQL Express? MySQL? SQLite? PostgreSQL?

Also, I would like it to be able to handle Stored Procedures.

It is a small app, and I really need a light weight database to handle some data.

Thanks.

Comment: This may get closed as SO does not like opinion-based questions.  But before it does - I found SQLite really easy to use.  I was looking for a zero-config, no-need-to-install-a-db-server solution myself, and I used sqlite.  I have also dabbled in 'SQL Server compact' And that may be good too.

Comment: My opinion is SQL Express. It installs with all the connector classes. I connect to Postgres, MySQl and SQL server, and SQL is the most stable and fewest dependencies.

Comment: You should at least define some criteria. All embedded databases are quite similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite is easy to use, configure and deploy. Can be used on client machine with a single DLL that doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: I would recommend the same. It's a piece of cake and performs well.

Comment: There is a plugin for firefox that allows you to open and modify a sqlite database.  Essentially it's a mini sql management studio for sqlite. I find it useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)?

Totally, integrated with your Microsoft ecosystem. It [does not support stored procedures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx?Redirected=true) though...

Answer (score 0):

Another product we are using for remote deployed sites is from SyBase Advantage Database Server.  It works with a DLL too, but for C#, you just need to install the .Net provider elements and good to go.

This was based the end-machines were not allowed to have any "services" running, and the machines would all be "locked down" so no such "server" product could be installed.  I also considered SQLite and actually did some comparisons and populated a few tables with roughly 50,000 records in a parent table and obviously more in child tables.  We ran some performance tests and found the Advantage Database Server was actually better with respect to performance.

We also needed the capability of working the data based on a possible network "share" drive and that worked too without any difficulty, just changed the connection path to that of the shared location and all was good to go.